# Removing Spaces in Python not working

Tags: python, palindrome, spaces, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove spaces.
I have tried everything from previous threads including `re.sub`

Code:

```
wordinput = (input("Input:\n"))
wordinput = wordinput.lower()
cleanword = wordinput.replace(" ","")
cleanword = wordinput.replace(",","")
cleanword = wordinput.replace(".","")
revword = cleanword [::-1]
print(cleanword)
print(revword)
print("Output:")
if (cleanword == revword):
    print('"The word ' + wordinput + ' is a palindrome!"')
else:
    print('"Unfortunately the word ' + wordinput + ' is not a palindrome. :(')
```

Output:

```
Input:
mr owl ate my metal worm 
mr owl ate my metal worm
mrow latem ym eta lwo rm
Output:
"Unfortunately the word mr owl ate my metal worm is not a palindrome. :(
```

Comment: Your last replace overwrites the previous 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
import re
cleanword = re.sub(r'\W+', '', wordinput.lower())
```

Comment: very clean way of doing it. nice

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is here:

```
cleanword = wordinput.replace(" ","")
cleanword = wordinput.replace(",","")
cleanword = wordinput.replace(".","")
```

You are not saving the results of the previous replace.

Try:

```
cleanword = wordinput.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

[@StephenRauch explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102129/9209546) your problem well.

But here is a better way to implement your logic:

```
chars = ',. '
wordinput = 'mr owl ate my metal worm '
cleanword = wordinput.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, chars)))

# 'mrowlatemymetalworm'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wordinput = (input("Input:\n"))
cleanword=''.join([e for e in wordinput.lower() if e not in ", ."])
```

You could try this comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
wordinput = raw_input("Input:\n")

cleanword =''.join([x for x in wordinput.lower() if x not in (',','.',' ')])

if cleanword[:] == cleanword[::-1]:

    print ('"The word ' + wordinput + ' is a palindrome!"')

else:
    print ('"The word ' + wordinput + ' is not a palindrome!"')
```

Answer (score 1):

After first replace, on subsequent replace, you need to use `cleanword` which is the updated string instead of `wordinput`. You can try following:

```
wordinput = (input("Input:\n"))
wordinput = wordinput.lower()
cleanword = wordinput.replace(" ","")

# updating 'cleanword' and saving it 
cleanword = cleanword.replace(",","")
cleanword = cleanword.replace(".","")

revword = cleanword [::-1]
print(cleanword)
print(revword)
print("Output:")

if (cleanword == revword):
    print('"The word ' + wordinput + ' is a palindrome!"')
else:
    print('"Unfortunately the word ' + wordinput + ' is not a palindrome. :(')
```